# LockerService, touch events and coordinates

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

In the past I did access coordinates from touch events like this

```
myCompElement.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
    var touchObj = event.changedTouches[0];
    var startX = parseInt(touchObj.clientX);
});
```

but the LockerService prevents accessing `event.touches` and `event.changedTouches` on any touch event object.

Is there any workaround accessing coordinates from touch events? What is the recommended way by Salesforce doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both event.touches and event.changedTouches were not exposed but are being added. The fix is will be published next week.

Comment: Thank you for that info - good to hear you are aware pushing in the right direction. But is there any overview what API LockerService is supporting? It's sometimes really hard finding when sth. is broken to identify why - an API overview would be my first table to look.

Comment: This is still an issue as of July 8th - did the fix not make it in time?

Comment: No, it did not make it, the fix is slightly more complex than expected.

Comment: I'm still seeing the same behaviour - is there an ETA for when this might be fixed? I'm getting error reports from people using my SignatureCapture from the component exchange in Salesforce1 and they can't disable the locker service as these are new orgs since Summer 16. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks JF for the helpful information @ Dreamforce - please don't forget to put the coordinate information of event.touches[] to your roadmap!

Comment: I have facing same issue but I am wondering how the touches objects working fine in UI:scrollWrapper component in lighting framework. Could you please tell me any one if the touches object exposed in lighting for now?. if not please tell me workaround if any.

Comment: @JFParadis Suddenly started facing this issue from today onwards(in iPhone, iOS version 10.3.1) when touching inside a chart rendered by Highcharts (That too only in scatter chart).

Comment: @SE_User which version of High Charts are you using? I will look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the response @JFParadis. I'm using 5.0.12(Yes, the latest stable release which is strict mode compliant). Please see:- [e.touches.item is not a function Error on touching Highcharts report in Salesforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185183/e-touches-item-is-not-a-function-error-on-touching-highcharts-report-in-salesfor) Ravi Jayaramappa has created a case:-`W-4167295`. Would be great if you could provide a workaround for the same. Thank you once again.

Comment: @SE_User Interesting.... the bug would suggest that this feature has never worked. However, you indicate that the problem began on the 20th?

Comment: I don't think this can be called a specific feature, this issue is specific for scatter chart & activity gauge chart as  well. (`In other Highcharts reports[like bubble chart, stacked column chart] which are being rendered, there's no such issue when touched anywhere inside the chart(also the tooltips are coming in fine) even the download functionality is working as well.`)

Comment: @JFParadis And yes, you're right, there wasn't any such issue in scatter chart as well and we were able to see the tooltip and also drilldown by touching the scatter chart. Not sure why suddenly this issue came up in all the mobile devices including Android and iOS(Maybe after one of your patches?[Just a wild guess, I doubt patch 14]). 
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @SE_User, that's great information to help us root out the cause.

Comment: @SE_User, I have posted the root cause and a workaround on the other thread: 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185183/e-touches-item-is-not-a-function-error-on-touching-highcharts-report-in-salesfor