# e.touches.item is not a function Error on touching Highcharts report in Salesforce1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, locker-service, highcharts

Error popover displayed when user touches the Highcharts report in iPads and mobile devices(both Android and in iPhone).

Here's the screenshot of the error popup displayed in iPad on touching the graph:-

[image: Error pop up]

Screenshot of the error in Nexus 6P:-
[image: Android error pop up]

Error:

> e.touches.item is not a function....

**Component code:-**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                           $Resource.summer17resources + '/jQuery_V1.js',
                            $Resource.highcharts + '/highcharts.js'
          )}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterLoad}" /> 
    <aura:attribute name="isResourcesLoaded" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>

</aura:component>
```

**Controller:-**

```
({
    afterLoad : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isResourcesLoaded",true);
    }
})
```

**Helper:-**

```
({
    drawChart : function(component, helper) {
        if(component.isValid() && component.get("v.isResourcesLoaded") ){
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart('container',{
                chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Height (cm)'
        },
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Weight (kg)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 100,
        y: 70,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 5,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Female',
        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
        data: [[161.2, 51.6], [167.5, 59.0], [159.5, 49.2], [157.0, 63.0], [155.8, 53.6],
            [170.0, 59.0], [159.1, 47.6], [166.0, 69.8], [176.2, 66.8], [160.2, 75.2],
            [172.5, 55.2], [170.9, 54.2], [172.9, 62.5], [153.4, 42.0], [160.0, 50.0],
            [147.2, 49.8], [168.2, 49.2], [175.0, 73.2], [157.0, 47.8], [167.6, 68.8],
            [159.5, 50.6], [175.0, 82.5], [166.8, 57.2], [176.5, 87.8], [170.2, 72.8],
            [174.0, 54.5], [173.0, 59.8], [179.9, 67.3], [170.5, 67.8], [160.0, 47.0],
            [154.4, 46.2], [162.0, 55.0], [176.5, 83.0], [160.0, 54.4], [152.0, 45.8],
            [162.1, 53.6], [170.0, 73.2], [160.2, 52.1], [161.3, 67.9], [166.4, 56.6],
            [168.9, 62.3], [163.8, 58.5], [167.6, 54.5], [160.0, 50.2], [161.3, 60.3],
            [167.6, 58.3], [165.1, 56.2], [160.0, 50.2], [170.0, 72.9], [157.5, 59.8],
            [167.6, 61.0], [160.7, 69.1], [163.2, 55.9], [152.4, 46.5], [157.5, 54.3],
            [168.3, 54.8], [180.3, 60.7], [165.5, 60.0], [165.0, 62.0], [164.5, 60.3],
            [156.0, 52.7], [160.0, 74.3], [163.0, 62.0], [165.7, 73.1], [161.0, 80.0],
            [162.0, 54.7], [166.0, 53.2], [174.0, 75.7], [172.7, 61.1], [167.6, 55.7],
            [151.1, 48.7], [164.5, 52.3], [163.5, 50.0], [152.0, 59.3], [169.0, 62.5],
            [164.0, 55.7], [161.2, 54.8], [155.0, 45.9], [170.0, 70.6], [176.2, 67.2],
            [170.0, 69.4], [162.5, 58.2], [170.3, 64.8], [164.1, 71.6], [169.5, 52.8],
            [163.2, 59.8], [154.5, 49.0], [159.8, 50.0], [173.2, 69.2], [170.0, 55.9],
            [161.4, 63.4], [169.0, 58.2], [166.2, 58.6], [159.4, 45.7], [162.5, 52.2],
            [159.0, 48.6], [162.8, 57.8], [159.0, 55.6], [179.8, 66.8], [162.9, 59.4],
            [161.0, 53.6], [151.1, 73.2], [168.2, 53.4], [168.9, 69.0], [173.2, 58.4],
            [171.8, 56.2], [178.0, 70.6], [164.3, 59.8], [163.0, 72.0], [168.5, 65.2],
            [166.8, 56.6], [172.7, 105.2], [163.5, 51.8], [169.4, 63.4], [167.8, 59.0],
            [159.5, 47.6], [167.6, 63.0], [161.2, 55.2], [160.0, 45.0], [163.2, 54.0],
            [162.2, 50.2], [161.3, 60.2], [149.5, 44.8], [157.5, 58.8], [163.2, 56.4],
            [172.7, 62.0], [155.0, 49.2], [156.5, 67.2], [164.0, 53.8], [160.9, 54.4],
            [162.8, 58.0], [167.0, 59.8], [160.0, 54.8], [160.0, 43.2], [168.9, 60.5],
            [158.2, 46.4], [156.0, 64.4], [160.0, 48.8], [167.1, 62.2], [158.0, 55.5],
            [167.6, 57.8], [156.0, 54.6], [162.1, 59.2], [173.4, 52.7], [159.8, 53.2],
            [170.5, 64.5], [159.2, 51.8], [157.5, 56.0], [161.3, 63.6], [162.6, 63.2],
            [160.0, 59.5], [168.9, 56.8], [165.1, 64.1], [162.6, 50.0], [165.1, 72.3],
            [166.4, 55.0], [160.0, 55.9], [152.4, 60.4], [170.2, 69.1], [162.6, 84.5],
            [170.2, 55.9], [158.8, 55.5], [172.7, 69.5], [167.6, 76.4], [162.6, 61.4],
            [167.6, 65.9], [156.2, 58.6], [175.2, 66.8], [172.1, 56.6], [162.6, 58.6],
            [160.0, 55.9], [165.1, 59.1], [182.9, 81.8], [166.4, 70.7], [165.1, 56.8],
            [177.8, 60.0], [165.1, 58.2], [175.3, 72.7], [154.9, 54.1], [158.8, 49.1],
            [172.7, 75.9], [168.9, 55.0], [161.3, 57.3], [167.6, 55.0], [165.1, 65.5],
            [175.3, 65.5], [157.5, 48.6], [163.8, 58.6], [167.6, 63.6], [165.1, 55.2],
            [165.1, 62.7], [168.9, 56.6], [162.6, 53.9], [164.5, 63.2], [176.5, 73.6],
            [168.9, 62.0], [175.3, 63.6], [159.4, 53.2], [160.0, 53.4], [170.2, 55.0],
            [162.6, 70.5], [167.6, 54.5], [162.6, 54.5], [160.7, 55.9], [160.0, 59.0],
            [157.5, 63.6], [162.6, 54.5], [152.4, 47.3], [170.2, 67.7], [165.1, 80.9],
            [172.7, 70.5], [165.1, 60.9], [170.2, 63.6], [170.2, 54.5], [170.2, 59.1],
            [161.3, 70.5], [167.6, 52.7], [167.6, 62.7], [165.1, 86.3], [162.6, 66.4],
            [152.4, 67.3], [168.9, 63.0], [170.2, 73.6], [175.2, 62.3], [175.2, 57.7],
            [160.0, 55.4], [165.1, 104.1], [174.0, 55.5], [170.2, 77.3], [160.0, 80.5],
            [167.6, 64.5], [167.6, 72.3], [167.6, 61.4], [154.9, 58.2], [162.6, 81.8],
            [175.3, 63.6], [171.4, 53.4], [157.5, 54.5], [165.1, 53.6], [160.0, 60.0],
            [174.0, 73.6], [162.6, 61.4], [174.0, 55.5], [162.6, 63.6], [161.3, 60.9],
            [156.2, 60.0], [149.9, 46.8], [169.5, 57.3], [160.0, 64.1], [175.3, 63.6],
            [169.5, 67.3], [160.0, 75.5], [172.7, 68.2], [162.6, 61.4], [157.5, 76.8],
            [176.5, 71.8], [164.4, 55.5], [160.7, 48.6], [174.0, 66.4], [163.8, 67.3]]

    }, {
        name: 'Male',
        color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
        data: [[174.0, 65.6], [175.3, 71.8], [193.5, 80.7], [186.5, 72.6], [187.2, 78.8],
            [181.5, 74.8], [184.0, 86.4], [184.5, 78.4], [175.0, 62.0], [184.0, 81.6],
            [180.0, 76.6], [177.8, 83.6], [192.0, 90.0], [176.0, 74.6], [174.0, 71.0],
            [184.0, 79.6], [192.7, 93.8], [171.5, 70.0], [173.0, 72.4], [176.0, 85.9],
            [176.0, 78.8], [180.5, 77.8], [172.7, 66.2], [176.0, 86.4], [173.5, 81.8],
            [178.0, 89.6], [180.3, 82.8], [180.3, 76.4], [164.5, 63.2], [173.0, 60.9],
            [183.5, 74.8], [175.5, 70.0], [188.0, 72.4], [189.2, 84.1], [172.8, 69.1],
            [170.0, 59.5], [182.0, 67.2], [170.0, 61.3], [177.8, 68.6], [184.2, 80.1],
            [186.7, 87.8], [171.4, 84.7], [172.7, 73.4], [175.3, 72.1], [180.3, 82.6],
            [182.9, 88.7], [188.0, 84.1], [177.2, 94.1], [172.1, 74.9], [167.0, 59.1],
            [169.5, 75.6], [174.0, 86.2], [172.7, 75.3], [182.2, 87.1], [164.1, 55.2],
            [163.0, 57.0], [171.5, 61.4], [184.2, 76.8], [174.0, 86.8], [174.0, 72.2],
            [177.0, 71.6], [186.0, 84.8], [167.0, 68.2], [171.8, 66.1], [182.0, 72.0],
            [167.0, 64.6], [177.8, 74.8], [164.5, 70.0], [192.0, 101.6], [175.5, 63.2],
            [171.2, 79.1], [181.6, 78.9], [167.4, 67.7], [181.1, 66.0], [177.0, 68.2],
            [174.5, 63.9], [177.5, 72.0], [170.5, 56.8], [182.4, 74.5], [197.1, 90.9],
            [180.1, 93.0], [175.5, 80.9], [180.6, 72.7], [184.4, 68.0], [175.5, 70.9],
            [180.6, 72.5], [177.0, 72.5], [177.1, 83.4], [181.6, 75.5], [176.5, 73.0],
            [175.0, 70.2], [174.0, 73.4], [165.1, 70.5], [177.0, 68.9], [192.0, 102.3],
            [176.5, 68.4], [169.4, 65.9], [182.1, 75.7], [179.8, 84.5], [175.3, 87.7],
            [184.9, 86.4], [177.3, 73.2], [167.4, 53.9], [178.1, 72.0], [168.9, 55.5],
            [157.2, 58.4], [180.3, 83.2], [170.2, 72.7], [177.8, 64.1], [172.7, 72.3],
            [165.1, 65.0], [186.7, 86.4], [165.1, 65.0], [174.0, 88.6], [175.3, 84.1],
            [185.4, 66.8], [177.8, 75.5], [180.3, 93.2], [180.3, 82.7], [177.8, 58.0],
            [177.8, 79.5], [177.8, 78.6], [177.8, 71.8], [177.8, 116.4], [163.8, 72.2],
            [188.0, 83.6], [198.1, 85.5], [175.3, 90.9], [166.4, 85.9], [190.5, 89.1],
            [166.4, 75.0], [177.8, 77.7], [179.7, 86.4], [172.7, 90.9], [190.5, 73.6],
            [185.4, 76.4], [168.9, 69.1], [167.6, 84.5], [175.3, 64.5], [170.2, 69.1],
            [190.5, 108.6], [177.8, 86.4], [190.5, 80.9], [177.8, 87.7], [184.2, 94.5],
            [176.5, 80.2], [177.8, 72.0], [180.3, 71.4], [171.4, 72.7], [172.7, 84.1],
            [172.7, 76.8], [177.8, 63.6], [177.8, 80.9], [182.9, 80.9], [170.2, 85.5],
            [167.6, 68.6], [175.3, 67.7], [165.1, 66.4], [185.4, 102.3], [181.6, 70.5],
            [172.7, 95.9], [190.5, 84.1], [179.1, 87.3], [175.3, 71.8], [170.2, 65.9],
            [193.0, 95.9], [171.4, 91.4], [177.8, 81.8], [177.8, 96.8], [167.6, 69.1],
            [167.6, 82.7], [180.3, 75.5], [182.9, 79.5], [176.5, 73.6], [186.7, 91.8],
            [188.0, 84.1], [188.0, 85.9], [177.8, 81.8], [174.0, 82.5], [177.8, 80.5],
            [171.4, 70.0], [185.4, 81.8], [185.4, 84.1], [188.0, 90.5], [188.0, 91.4],
            [182.9, 89.1], [176.5, 85.0], [175.3, 69.1], [175.3, 73.6], [188.0, 80.5],
            [188.0, 82.7], [175.3, 86.4], [170.5, 67.7], [179.1, 92.7], [177.8, 93.6],
            [175.3, 70.9], [182.9, 75.0], [170.8, 93.2], [188.0, 93.2], [180.3, 77.7],
            [177.8, 61.4], [185.4, 94.1], [168.9, 75.0], [185.4, 83.6], [180.3, 85.5],
            [174.0, 73.9], [167.6, 66.8], [182.9, 87.3], [160.0, 72.3], [180.3, 88.6],
            [167.6, 75.5], [186.7, 101.4], [175.3, 91.1], [175.3, 67.3], [175.9, 77.7],
            [175.3, 81.8], [179.1, 75.5], [181.6, 84.5], [177.8, 76.6], [182.9, 85.0],
            [177.8, 102.5], [184.2, 77.3], [179.1, 71.8], [176.5, 87.9], [188.0, 94.3],
            [174.0, 70.9], [167.6, 64.5], [170.2, 77.3], [167.6, 72.3], [188.0, 87.3],
            [174.0, 80.0], [176.5, 82.3], [180.3, 73.6], [167.6, 74.1], [188.0, 85.9],
            [180.3, 73.2], [167.6, 76.3], [183.0, 65.9], [183.0, 90.9], [179.1, 89.1],
            [170.2, 62.3], [177.8, 82.7], [179.1, 79.1], [190.5, 98.2], [177.8, 84.1],
            [180.3, 83.2], [180.3, 83.2]]
    }]

            });
        }
    }
})
```

**Renderer:-**

```
({
    afterRender: function(component, helper) {
        this.superAfterRender();
        helper.drawChart(component, helper);
    },
    rerender: function(component, helper) {
        this.superRerender();       
        helper.drawChart(component, helper);
    }
})
```

**Static Resource:-** jQuery version 2.2.4 and Highcharts- https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js

Also, I think this started after Salesforce updated to patch 14 in various instances. (Not 100% sure though) Doubtful since, I did not encounter this error 24 hours back and also since some instances are still in patch 13.6.

This happens only in iPads and mobile devices (Android and iOS) and both are in latest versions.
iOS version 10.3.3 and Android 7.

Have faced similar issue in older iOS versions (*9 point*).

Would be grateful if any of you could provide any insights regarding the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SE_User, there was indeed a fix in patch 14 in Aura Framework that introduced the regression. In fact, that error always existed (W-4167295 is the correct fix) but that error was allowed to fail silently. By fixing the error reporting, patch 14 makes the error visible to the user as you posted.

[image: Error]

Since W-4167295 would most likely be too intrusive for a patch, you can introduce the following workaround (tested on iOS simulator).

In `highcharts-5.0.12.js`, replace the line following comment `// iOS (#2757)`:

```
            // iOS (#2757)
            ePos = e.touches ? (e.touches.length ? e.touches.item(0) : e.changedTouches[0]) : e;
```

with this one

```
            // iOS (#2757)
            ePos = e.touches ? (e.touches.length && typeof e.touches.item === 'function' ? e.touches.item(0) : e.changedTouches[0]) : e;
```

The check will ensure that your code continues to work when the fix is in, but meanwhile will fallback to using the `changedTouches` array.

[image: fix]

Let us know how it goes. Thanks for the detailed description.

Comment: Thank you very much @JFParadis. Yes, I made the edit in the source code as you suggested and it's working fine now. Thank you. :) [Now, it's only the [export functionality that isn't working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/185900/29317). But I think as Ravi Jayaramappa has said it would only be fixed in Winter'18 right?] `W-4063448 is the bug associated with the fix`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like e.touches is returning an array instead of a wrapped(secure) TouchList. I have filed a bug for Locker Service team to support a SecureTouchList(bug no: W-4167295)
In the meanwhile as a workaround, can you continue accessing the elements by index just like you would access array elements by index?

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into it and filing bug. You're suggesting to edit Highcharts source file as a workaround?

Comment: Also, there was something very similar an year back which @JFParadis had updated on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/129168/29317 , if this would be of any help to you.