# Highcharts Scatter chart issue while exporting as JPEG and PNG

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, locker-service, highcharts

Error popover displayed when user tries to export (offline exporting) highcharts scatter chart as JPEG or PNG format inside Lightning components.

Here's the screenshot of the error popup:-

[image]

Error:

> Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'

Exporting works fine with SVG as well as PDF. The issue exists when we do **offline exporting** as JPEG or PNG.

Can anyone help me out in this ?

Answer (score 4):

This is a known feature gap in Locker Service. We have fixed it in winter 18 release. W-4063448 is the bug associated with the fix.
If you are curious about the fix, please take a look at this commit in our open source repo https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/commit/90f778b8e3abe147d130ae8ba243681d2d4a619a

Comment: So are you suggesting that we should wait till winter 18 release ?
Or is there any quick workaround we could use.

Comment: Hi @RaviJayaramappa  Any workaround for this issue or waiting till Winter 18 release is the only option?

Comment: @SE_User There are no workarounds as of now. But the good news is that Winter 18 is being deployed to all productions instances in the coming weeks. All SandBox instances are already on Winter 18.

Comment: That sounds good. Thank you @RaviJayaramappa for the update! :)